# How to construct a model instance from multiple column with JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have this scenario, where there is three entities, each having like around 20 columns, assume all are unique names, 20*3 is 60 unique column names. Then I need to fetch some particular fields like 30 fields from them by joining all 3. So I have the mappings in place in each Entity. Then to select only this 30 fields I understand I should only select them, using multi select. But is there an efficient way to do this? Like instead of writing 30 column names in my code, can I have a model which defines all these fields and then **pass this model in select clause**, so it selects the fields, or something similar.

Then Entity 1 :-

```
public class CourseEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
long id;

String name;

String descr;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "univ_id")
UniversityEntity university;
```

Entity 2 :-

```
public class StudentEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "last_name")
private String lastName;

@Column(name = "grad_year")
private int gradYear;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "course_id")
CourseEntity courses;
```

Entity 3 :-

```
public class UniversityEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
long id;

String name;

String desrc;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "university")
CourseEntity courses;
}
```

The model object I want :-

```
public class StudentModel {

private int disbursementId;
private String payeeId;
private String courseName;
private String offeredBy;

}
```

But the place I am concerned about is,
Select Query :-

```
    CriteriaQuery<StudentModel> criteriaQuery = cb.createQuery(StudentModel.class);

    Root<StudentEntity> root = criteriaQuery.from(StudentEntity.class);
    Join<StudentEntity, CourseEntity> student_course = root.join("courses");
    Join<CourseEntity, UniversityEntity> university_course = student_course.join("university"); 
    criteriaQuery.multiselect(
            root.get("id").alias("disbursement_id")
            , root.get("firstName").alias("payee_id")
            , student_course.get("name").alias("course_name")
            , university_course.get("name").alias("offered_by")
            )
            .where(cb.equal(root.get("gradYear"), 2015));

    TypedQuery<StudentModel> query = em.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
    List<StudentModel> results = query.getResultList();
```

Can we actually pass like,

```
    CriteriaQuery<StudentModel> criteriaQuery = cb.createQuery(StudentModel.class);

    Root<StudentEntity> root = criteriaQuery.from(StudentEntity.class);
    Join<StudentEntity, CourseEntity> student_course = root.join("courses");
    Join<CourseEntity, UniversityEntity> university_course = student_course.join("university"); 
    criteriaQuery.multiselect(
            **StudentModel**
            )
            .where(cb.equal(root.get("gradYear"), 2015));

    TypedQuery<StudentModel> query = em.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
    List<StudentModel> results = query.getResultList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can contruct a model instance by using `CriteriaBuild#construct` rather than `multiselect`.

Your model class must have a constructor taking all fields as parameters:

```
public StudentModel(int disbursementId, String payeeId /**...**/) {/**...**/}
```

then you can use like this:

```
criteriaQuery.select(cb.construct(StudentModel.class, root.get("id"), root.get("firstName") /**...**/));
```

Comment: It's the same as getting it with TypedQuery<StudentModel> right? I wish to entirely omit the `root.get("id"), root.get("firstName")` in the select statement, and rather have that definition in the StudentModel itself, something like, `StudentModel { @Referes("StudentEntity.id") int disbursement_id; }` and let the model be defining the columns to select from the joined tables